# Use swipe to switch blocks for mobile screen

Tags: blocks, theming

In the mobile version of my site I would like to use swipe to cycle through different blocks. 
E.g. a certain block (view) is displayed and swiping the screen would show the next one in the same region. Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if this would work, but you could install a module to add a view as a field. then use either a multi-value field or one per content instance. Create a view on that field and tie the view to your slider/carousel/rotator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with a views - slideshow, like [owl](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel) or [slick](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick), where you show these blocks using [views_block_area](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area).

Show this view by css-media-queries, in which you hide the normal content ..
like:

```
.my-view {display: block;}
.my-block {display: none;}
@media(min-width:34em){}
@media(min-width:48em){
  .my-view {display: none;}
  .my-block {display: block;}
}
@media(min-width:62em){}
@media(min-width:75em){}
```

more info on the web or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries

Comment: The problem is that i would like to use a view generated block, while the module descriptions says: "Blocks that are generated by views can not be selected, these blocks can not be inserted into views."
So, I would need to create a view that slides through other views. Or just put views in a carousel.

Comment: Place the view twice with different displays using [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)